# Array nullpointerException ERROR

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

Here is my partial code:

```
`private Instrumento[] repInst;
 public RepositorioInstrumentos(){
    Instrumento[] repInst = new Instrumento[20];
 }
 private int getPos(int id){
        int pos= -1;
        for(int i=0; i<tam; i++){
            if (repInst[i]!=null&&repInst[i].getId()==id){
                pos=i;
                i=tam;
            }
        }
        return pos;
    }`
```

I keep getting a null Poiter exception in this line:

```
 `if (repInst[i]!=null&&repInst[i].getId()==id){`
```

all positions of repInst are null. I thought that putting that " if " he would skip it and return pos = -1.

why isn't working?

Comment: Well...if all positions of `repInst` are `null`, then the logic to actually do anything with the instance contained in location `i` wouldn't be invoked.  The likely case is that there is some fun with autoboxing and `null` with `getId()`.

Comment: where is your tam variable ?

Comment: Why u initializing new Arraylist in constructor? and even u have not initialize main one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

repInst is local varible in constructor

```
private Instrumento[] repInst;
public RepositorioInstrumentos(){
 repInst = new Instrumento[20];
 }
private int getPos(int id){
    int pos= -1;
    for(int i=0; i<tam; i++){
        if (repInst[i]!=null&&repInst[i].getId()==id){
            pos=i;
            i=tam;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `repInst` in the constructor then access its method beacuse if you access its method without initializing it you will get `NullPointerException` and what is the value of `tam` varaible may be its value is greater then arrays lenth then it will also throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
private Instrumento[] repInst;
 public RepositorioInstrumentos(){
   repInst = new Instrumento[20];
 }
 private int getPos(int id){
        int pos= -1;
        int tam=20;
//tam variable value should b less then arrays length
        for(int i=0; i<tam; i++){
            if (repInst[i]!=null&&repInst[i].getId()==id){
                pos=i;
                i=tam;
            }
        }
        return pos;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do One change. Initialize your this array out side of Constructor.

```
Instrumento[] repInst = new Instrumento[20];
```

or initialize it with Object of that.